# How to display number with zero decimal place in plotchar() with pine-script?

Tags: pine-script

I am displaying a variable `display_num` on tradingview using pinescript. Here's the code;

```
int display_num = 0
display_num := get_display_num()
plotchar(display_num, title="display_num ", char="", location=location.top, color=#FFFFFF)
```

`display_num` is displayed with 2 decimal places. However, it is integer type with no decimal  places. How do I display `display_num` as an integer with no decimal places?

I am using pinescript v5 on TradingView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `precision=0` to your `indicator()` call but this will affect all your outputs.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", precision=0)
plot(1)    // 1
plot(1.25) // 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any solution to choosing the precision for specific outputs?

Comment: No, that's not possible at the moment.